# Dividing numbers in java

Tags: java

Hey people of Stackoverflow! I just have a question about an error that I came across while doing this lesson on Java online. So this is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradesAndPoints {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Type in your score between (0-27): ");
        Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = ask.nextInt();

        int result = (num/27);

        System.out.println(result);
```

The error is: whenever I run the code with the variable "num" being any int value, it prints out to be 0. Can someone explain to me why this error occurs and a solution I can implement to solve this?

Comment: *whenever I run the code with the variable "num" being any int value, it prints out to be 0.* Really? Have you tried 27?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing this, you're diving integers. This, by definition, will get you an integer that is truncated.

```
5 / 10 = 0
```

If you turn one of them into a float (by adding a `.` at the end), you will get floating point division, which is what you're looking for.

```
5. / 10 = 0.5
5 / 10. = 0.5
5.0 / 10.0 = 0.5
```